# WCS8 Solr Preprocess failed : Error SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710, SQLERRMC=WCSSTGAP.XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5, solr

Our Solr Pro-process is failing with below error:

> [2018/08/28 14:31:36:104 CDT] 00000001 W
>   com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataimport.preprocess.AbstractDataPreProcessor:createDBTable(Connection,
>   String, String) create XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0 with error: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-601, SQLSTATE=42710,
>   SQLERRMC=WCSSTGAP.XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0;TABLE, DRIVER=4.19.49

I suspect that DROP table XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0 is failing and ultimately causing the creation of the existing table.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The -601 happens because table WCSSTGAP.XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0 already exists , so it cannot be created again while it exists.

Either drop that table manually and retry, or check back in the log file(s) to find if a previous DROP TABLE WCSSTGAP.XI_CATENTRY_PRICE_0  did fail (and then solve that problem first). You will need to find root cause.